# awk print string without fixed width formatting?

Tags: awk

Is there a way to have awk not print a fixed width column?

For example:

```
"9", "TAYLOR TOWER, JACOB B.   "
"9", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS-EAST"
"AR", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER     "
"B1", "NEWARK RESIDENCE HALL    "
"B2", "NEWARK RESIDENCE HALL    "
"CC", "OHIO STADIUM             "
"D1", "TELECOM NETWORK CENTER  "
"DC", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER     "
"EN", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER     "
"GR", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS-EAST"
"LL", "RANEY COMMONS, 2ND LT. AL"
"MZ", "PHYSICS RESEARCH        "
"MZ", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER     "
"NS", "STARLING LOVING HALL    "
"P1", "OHIO STADIUM             "
"P2", "OHIO STADIUM             "
"P3", "OHIO STADIUM             "
```

I want this to be printed as:

```
"9", "TAYLOR TOWER, JACOB B."
"9", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS-EAST"
"AR", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER"
"B1", "NEWARK RESIDENCE HALL"
"B2", "NEWARK RESIDENCE HALL"
"CC", "OHIO STADIUM"
"D1", "TELECOM NETWORK CENTER"
"DC", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER"
"EN", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER"
"GR", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS-EAST"
"LL", "RANEY COMMONS, 2ND LT. AL"
"MZ", "PHYSICS RESEARCH"
"MZ", "SCHOTTENSTEIN CENTER"
"NS", "STARLING LOVING HALL"
"P1", "OHIO STADIUM"
"P2", "OHIO STADIUM"
"P3", "OHIO STADIUM"
```

Notice the second field in this text has no whitespace inside the quotes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWK (gawk/nawk)

```
{sub(/[ ]*\"$/, "\"");print}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sed instead of awk, although you can do `gsub` in awk if you must:

```
sed -e 's/  *"$/"/'
```

Meaning "turn one or more spaces followed by quote at the end of the line into just quote"